# outputText and inputText in f:facet of rich:column doesn't work - JSF

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to achieve external filtering using rich:dataTable which has sorting ability.

Here's what I have tried:

```
<rich:column sortBy="#{data.name}" id="name" filterMethod="#myBean.filter}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.currentName}"
                        id="nameFilterInput" onclick="Event.stop(event)" onkeypress="searchNameOnEnter(event, this);">
                                        <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="dataTable , ds"
                                            ignoreDupResponses="true" requestDelay="700" />
                                    </h:inputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{data.name}" />
</rich:column>
```

**Problem**: The input text field is overwriting the output text (the header name)

I've tried using h:panelGroup inside the f:facet, but the problem is the sort icon is rendered in the third row seperately.

What am I missing here?
Any help would be great.

**Updated**: @Christophe Roussy, here's the screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

As seen the inputText is overwriting the outputText.

**Update 2**: I saw a post here: https://community.jboss.org/thread/13046 which explains to use `<f:facet name="filter">` for inputText, but that seems to work only for rich:extendedDataTable.
Any way to make it work with rich:dataTable?

Comment: I have something similar and it shows both, do you have a screenshot ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<f:facet>` can have only one child. Wrap them in a `<h:panelGroup>`.

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:outputText ... />
        <h:inputText ... />
    </h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: If I use panelgroup is it possible to change the position of built-in sort icon? Inbetween the outputtext and inputtext?